# How to add button in header

Tags: java, android, button, header

[As-is image]http://sdrv.ms/1bx8Bxm
[To-be image]http://sdrv.ms/1aGADfo
We want to move the maintain button from context to header. We try a lot of method. some sample code but have error once we add in to our code. Can anyone help us pls?
the first image is what we are now, the second image is what we want to reach. 
Thank you so much!!!

[image]

[image]

our code for maintain button in xml is like this:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/maintain"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:text="Maintain"
android:background="#F77D03" />
```

Comment: Where is your code? what you have tried ?

Comment: that looks like a a button in action bar

Comment: why not using menu options?

Comment: we are newly in andorid actually, we dont know how to code like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in menu folder of resource
**main1.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_maintain"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Maintain"/>

</menu>
```

And this in `Activity`

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main1, menu);// Menu Resource, Menu
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_maintain:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 1 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! It's very useful!but now our header: as show below NextBusStopV1 is disappeared. now our interface is like this http://sdrv.ms/1goZ1nW. What should we do?

Comment: There is a "NextBusStopV1" on top in our orginal version, but now disappear, so what should i do? I need show this on top, thanks. so our target header is actually NextBusStopV1 and besides this, a Maintain button on the right hand

Comment: You are running ur app on device below API 11, if you still want actionbar use actionbar sherlock librery.